# display image from PhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiimage

I want to display an image selected from PhotoLibrary. The ImagePicker brings up the PhotoLibrary and I am able to select it but it wont display in the view.
I have the placeholder for displaying the image with a Image(uiImage: self.image) and frame 50x50.
How to update the image in the current view

```
struct AddContactView: View {

@State private var selectedPhoto: PhotosPickerItem?
@State private var selectedPhotoData: Data?


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            TextField("Full Name", text: $nameInput)
                .textContentType(.name)
                
            TextField("Phone Number", text: $phoneInput)
                .textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
            Spacer()
            //Text(Image(systemName: "Dummy"))
            ZStack {
                if let selectedPhotoData, let image = UIImage(data: selectedPhotoData) {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 150)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }
                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhoto, matching: .any (of:
                        [.images, .not(.livePhotos)])) {
                            Label("Select Photo", systemImage: "photo")
                }
                .tint(.blue)
                .onChange(of: selectedPhoto) { newPhoto in
                    Task{
                        if let data = try? await newPhoto!.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            selectedPhotoData?.append(data)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }
         

        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Add ")
        
    }
```

}`
[image: before_selection]
[image: after_selection]
After selection the image fills the screen and the select photo button moves to the center from the bottom. I want the image to go into a circle of size 64 just below my phone number text field. How can I do that.

Comment: `.resizable()`, `.scaledtoFit()`, `frame(width: 64, height: 64)` and `clipShape(Circle())`. Is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `.sheet` and `ImagePicker` with [`.photosPicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/photospicker(ispresented:selection:matching:preferreditemencoding:)/).

Here are some links to help with loading the transferable:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker
(Probably needs `.onChange`)

https://swiftwithmajid.com/2023/04/25/photospicker-in-swiftui/
( use `.task(id: selectedPhoto)` )

Comment: Changed the code to PhotosPicket and it worked. But after the selection the image fills the screen of current view and the select photo button moves to the center from the bottom. I want the image to go inside a circle of size 64 just below my phone number text field. How can I do that?